# Access SQL Count field where equals value

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access-2007

I am working on a table for a client where they desire only specific column value to be counted I have done one way of it but its not the outcome they need so it was out aside.

I have a table like this.(Note: Not actual table)

```
company_name | type  | ................
com A        | type1 | ................
com A        | type2 | ................
com B        | type1 | ................
com A        | type2 | ................
com A        | type1 | ................
com C        | type1 | ................
com C        | type2 | ................
com A        | type1 | ................
```

so on so forth with the type column though there are columns in it that they don't want counted at all

The table that is needed would look like this

```
company_name | Type1 | Type2 | ..........
com A        |   3   |   2   | ..........
com B        |   1   |   0   | ..........
com C        |   1   |   1   | ..........
```

What I'm getting so far is:

```
company_name | Type  | count | ..........
com A        | type1 |   3   | ..........
com A        | type2 |   2   | ..........
com B        | type1 |   1   | ..........
com C        | type1 |   1   | ..........
com C        | type2 |   1   | ..........
```

Please help I have been scratching my skull away over this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  company_name,
  SUM(IIF(Type = 'type1', 1, 0)) AS Type1,
  SUM(IIF(Type = 'type2', 1, 0)) AS Type2,
  SUM(IIF(Type = 'type3', 1, 0)) AS Type3
FROM table
GROUP BY company_name;
```

---

### Update

In MySQL, you can use the [`IF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) statement instead of Access's `IIF`, also you can write it without `IF` or `CASE` because of MySQL implicit conversions:

```
SELECT Promoter, 
  Sum(NoticeType = 'VARIATION')       AS 'Variation', 
  Sum(NoticeType = 'TWO HOURS AFTER') AS 'Two Hours After', 
  Sum(NoticeType = 'THREE MONTHS')    AS 'Three Months', 
  Sum(NoticeType = 'THREE DAY')       AS 'Three Day', 
  Sum(NoticeType = 'TEN DAY')         AS 'Ten Day' 
FROM notices 
GROUP BY Promoter;
```

Comment: Mahmoud Gamal there is no way i could thank you for this workes like a charm also thank you for rewriting it the first one was wrong. lol

Comment: SELECT `Promoter`, 
    Sum(IIf(`Notice Type`='VARIATION',1,0)) AS `Variation`, 
    Sum(IIf(`Notice Type`='TWO HOURS AFTER',1,0)) AS `Two Hours After`, 
    Sum(IIf(`Notice Type`='THREE MONTHS',1,0)) AS `Three Months`, 
    Sum(IIf(`Notice Type`='THREE DAY',1,0)) AS `Three Day`, 
    Sum(IIf(`Notice Type`='TEN DAY',1,0)) AS `Ten Day`
    FROM notices
    GROUP BY `Promoter`;

what would this be in MySQL